# Why do I get 'permission denied' when trying to 'cd' into a NFS share on Synology?

Tags: permissions, nfs, nas

I have two *NFS shares* configured the same way on my Synology NAS:

```
synology> sudo cat /etc/exports

/volumeUSB1/usbshare 192.168.1.10(ro,async,no_wdelay,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)
/volume1/Plex        192.168.1.10(ro,async,no_wdelay,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)
```

I'd like to mount these *NFS shares* on my Ubuntu:

```
ubuntu> sudo mkdir /mnt/Synology_USB
ubuntu> sudo mkdir /mnt/Synology_Plex

ubuntu> sudo mount synology:/volumeUSB1/usbshare /mnt/Synology_USB
ubuntu> sudo mount synology:/volume1/Plex /mnt/Synology_Plex

ubuntu> cd /mnt
ubuntu> ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Dec 20 09:22 Synology_Plex
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 13 19:09 Synology_WD2000GB

ubuntu> cd /mnt/Synology_USB
# No errors up until here, I can see all my files

ubuntu> cd /mnt/Synology_Plex
-bash: cd: /mnt/Synology_Plex/: Permission denied
```

I think that the difference could be caused by the fact that one is a USB drive (NTFS) and the other one is Synology's built in drive (btrfs) but for the world I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I use the following solution to access my synology NAS in 20.04. First I did sudo apt-get install cifs-utils and then created the mount point (which I tthink you have done). My fstab entry is //192.168.1.foo/share-name /mount-point/share-name cifs username=foo,password=foo,rw,uid=1000,gid=500 and the drive mounts perfectly each time.

Comment: @User24601 Thanks. Surprisingly the CIFS shares are working for me, as well, however I'd prefer using NFS over CIFS (1. because it's faster, 2. because I don't need to deal with credentials during automount).

Comment: Don't forget the credentials can be stored in a credentials file referenced in fstab. I had great problems trying to get NFS to work on my Synology NAS and in the end gave up and just used this method to mount and access the files. Did you set up NFS access within the Synology File Station?

Comment: (Yes, I just didn't want the hassle with storing of CIFS credentials, if possible). Yes, I enabled NFS on Synology (Control Panel) and on the shares, as well, exactly the same way. I have two NFS shares on the NAS. Strangely one of them works fine on Ubuntu, the other one shows access denied. I have no idea how to debug this :(